# How do I earn Dungeon Raid's Armed and Dangerous Achievment?

Tags: ios, dungeon-raid

Dungeon Raid explains that to earn the Armed and Dangerous achievement, you have to "upgrade an item to have 8 stats."  What does "stats" mean?  I'm confused exactly what I need to do to earn this trophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have to have an item have 8 stats or buffs. Like if your weapon had +1 strength, luck, spikes, draining, defense, luck, dexterity, and quick; then you would get the achievement.

Answer (score 0):

I think a stat is anything offered in the enchant or upgrade menu, such as Luck, Regen, Quickness, Spikes, Vitality, Str, +HP, etc.